# jQuery toogleClass or addClass removeClass cookie

Tags: jquery

I've been searching for weeks to create an cookie for Toogle Class, can please someone help me to combine my JavaScript Code:

button to activate:

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="fa fa-bars" id="menu-toggle"></a>
```

My JavaScript (jQuery):

```
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("smartBar");
    });
</script>
```

Here the cookie script that I want to combine:

```
/**
 * Cookie plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 Klaus Hartl (stilbuero.de)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 */

/**
 * Create a cookie with the given name and value and other optional parameters.
 *
 * @example $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
 * @desc Set the value of a cookie.
 * @example $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com', secure: true });
 * @desc Create a cookie with all available options.
 * @example $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
 * @desc Create a session cookie.
 * @example $.cookie('the_cookie', null);
 * @desc Delete a cookie by passing null as value. Keep in mind that you have to use the same path and domain
 *       used when the cookie was set.
 *
 * @param String name The name of the cookie.
 * @param String value The value of the cookie.
 * @param Object options An object literal containing key/value pairs to provide optional cookie attributes.
 * @option Number|Date expires Either an integer specifying the expiration date from now on in days or a Date object.
 *                             If a negative value is specified (e.g. a date in the past), the cookie will be deleted.
 *                             If set to null or omitted, the cookie will be a session cookie and will not be retained
 *                             when the the browser exits.
 * @option String path The value of the path atribute of the cookie (default: path of page that created the cookie).
 * @option String domain The value of the domain attribute of the cookie (default: domain of page that created the cookie).
 * @option Boolean secure If true, the secure attribute of the cookie will be set and the cookie transmission will
 *                        require a secure protocol (like HTTPS).
 * @type undefined
 *
 * @name $.cookie
 * @cat Plugins/Cookie
 * @author Klaus Hartl/klaus.hartl@stilbuero.de
 */

/**
 * Get the value of a cookie with the given name.
 *
 * @example $.cookie('the_cookie');
 * @desc Get the value of a cookie.
 *
 * @param String name The name of the cookie.
 * @return The value of the cookie.
 * @type String
 *
 * @name $.cookie
 * @cat Plugins/Cookie
 * @author Klaus Hartl/klaus.hartl@stilbuero.de
 */
jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
    if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
        options = options || {};
        if (value === null) {
            value = '';
            options = $.extend({}, options); // clone object since it's unexpected behavior if the expired property were changed
            options.expires = -1;
        }
        var expires = '';
        if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
            var date;
            if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
                date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            } else {
                date = options.expires;
            }
            expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
        }
        // NOTE Needed to parenthesize options.path and options.domain
        // in the following expressions, otherwise they evaluate to undefined
        // in the packed version for some reason...
        var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
        var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
        var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
        document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
    } else { // only name given, get cookie
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
};
```

I hope someone can help me. I'm wondering if it can work with toggleClass maybe it will work better with addClass and removeClass the #wrapper container must have add and removeClass with class smartBar.

---

I have try this but it don't works, here is the fiddle version:

```
jsfiddle.net/childx/xj2odr3j/4/
```

with the old script it works but not with the new and also i think addClass and removeClass must be changed because the smartBar class must be added on start of the website it is an opened sidebar.

Maybe you can help me to fix it?

Comment: Toggle class uses a function in and out. You can utilize that idea.

Comment: I use the cookie lib a lot to store the state of panels, and accordions and such for the users ui of my sites. I store the index order also for sortables, and so when the user returns, I read in the cookie value. If it has a index array in it, i then reorder my sortable to match it. If not, it just loads the list. Same concept for all of these things, just update the cookie value (used like dictionary with [index:key]) on events, and then read it in every time you load the content.

Comment: I have made this Fiddle to see it online: http://jsfiddle.net/childx/xj2odr3j/4/

Can someone please check it up? i searching for weeks for a working cookie

Answer (score 0):

You save the cookie value every toggle, and check it durring the load. This preserves state when returning.

```
//load cookie state
$("#menu-toggle").addClass($.cookie("toggleState")); //do this on load. if class exusts, will add value.

$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass(function(){
           //add class and cookie
           $(this).addClass("smartBar");
           $.cookie("toggleState", "smartBar");
        },function(){
           $(this).removeClass("smartBar");
           $.cookie("toggleState", "");
        });
    });
```